# javax.inject GWT error

Tags: gwt, guice, gwt-gin

HELP WITH THIS ERROR PLEASE!

Compiling module com.myapp.n.N
   Scanning for additional dependencies: file:/C:/development/n5fix/nube/src/com/myapp/n/client/N.java
      Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.diddiasix.nube.client.gin.GinServiceInjector'
         Rebinding com.myapp.n.client.gin.GinServiceInjector
            Invoking generator com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.GinjectorGenerator
               [ERROR] Generator 'com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.GinjectorGenerator' threw an exception while rebinding 'com.diddiasix.nube.client.gin.GinServiceInjector'
com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:

1) No implementation for javax.inject.Provider was bound.
  while locating javax.inject.Provider
    for parameter 9 at com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.BindingsProcessor.(BindingsProcessor.java:210)
  at com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.GinjectorGeneratorModule.configure(GinjectorGeneratorModule.java:59)

Comment: you should post some more info about what you are trying to do, perhaps even the source for `C:/development/n5fix/nube/src/com/myapp/n/client/N.java`

Comment: If you format it nicely, it'll be more likely to get good answers.

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/google-gin/issues/detail?id=133 says it's a dependency issue.

Check your GIN and Guice versions.

Answer (score 0):

We are using AppEngine and had the same issue.

After adding

guice-servlet-3.0.jar (and the other jars from the guice.zip)

to the classpath, the error has gone.